# Repeated items in Android spinner

Tags: android, kotlin, android-spinner

I have a spinner which I call in onCreate activity. The spinner takes data from the Room database. When I first run the spinner the data are shown correctly. But when I get back to the spinner I can see the same items multiple times. E.g. there should be only values of 11, 12, 13, 14, etc., not 11 or 12 twice (or sometimes even more times).

[image]

I call the function initSpinnerData() in onCreate Activity. I tried it in onResume activity, it shows the same result.

```
private fun initSpinnerData(){
        val allDevices = this?.let {
            ArrayAdapter<Any>(it, R.layout.simple_item_spinner, R.id.tv_simple_item)
        }
        zebraViewModel.getAllZebra()
            .observe(this, { devices ->
                devices?.forEach{
                    allDevices?.add(it)
                }
            } )
        spinner3.adapter = allDevices
        spinner3.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, position: Int, p3: Long) {
                if (parent != null) {
                    val idZebraString = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
                    idZebra = idZebraString.toInt()
                }
            }
            override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
                Toast.makeText(this@ZebraActivity, "You must choose some item", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because `.observe` method, which gets called at the start for every item and when single model changes, but you are calling `add` anyway, causing duplicates

try to check if this new item already exists in the adapter, if yes then do nothing or remove the old item and add a new one. e.g.

```
            devices?.forEach{
                if (allDevices.getPosition(it) < 0) allDevices?.add(it)
            }
```

that should work if you have proper model declaration (`toString()` and hashcode)